# Brick Tower Building Puzzle

Tags: python

I've been given a little brainteaser to solve.

The task is to make a function with a single integer parameter. You have to figure out how many different combination of tower patterns you can make with that given amount of bricks (each proceeding tower must be less in height than one previous, kind of like). There must be 2 or more towers, one right next to the other.

For example, if you were given 3 blocks you can only produce 1 combination of towers, one with a height of 2 and its neighbor having a height of 1:

```
|
| |
2 1
```

Given 4 you can only still produce one combination since the next tower must be shorter than the previous:

```
|
|
| |
3 1
```

Given 5 you can produce 2 combinations:

```
|
|
|
| |
4 1

|
| |
| |
3 2
```

I have a function that can do all of this, however they give the example that 200 blocks should produce 487067745. Which my function simply does not do. I don't know what I am doing wrong. A push in the right direction would be very much appreciated. My function now looks like this:

```
def answer(num):
    # divide the blocks so we have two towers, one with a height of n-1 and 
    # the other with a height of one
    l1 = num-1
    l2 = 1
    combinations = 0
    while True:
        if l1 > l2:
            # add 1 to the combinations along with how many combinations we 
            # can make using the blocks from tower two
            combinations += 1 + answer(l2)
        elif l1 == l2:
            # see if we can make additional towers out of the rightmost tower
            # and add that to the combinations
            combinations += answer( l2 )
        else:
            # if the first tower is smaller than or equal to the other tower 
            # then we stop trying to make combinations
            return combinations
        l1 -= 1
        l2 += 1
```

While this method does work for smaller numbers of bricks (returning 2 combinations for 5 blocks and 1 combination for 3 or 4 blocks), it does not work for much larger numbers that would be impossible to do on sheets of paper.

Comment: When
I \n
I \n
I I \n

is valid then , why can't we have 

I \n
I \n
I \n
I \n

Can you please clarify this one in question.

Comment: This question looks a little broad.  [Ask], questions posted here should provide a [MCVE], and please complete the 2-minute [tour] before editing your post

Comment: first check for smaller values - it will be easier check results on paper. You can always use `print()` to see what is going on in code - maybe it does not what you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) gives the generating function for the number of partitions of n with distinct parts as q(n) = product (1+x^k) for k=1..infinity. Given that you exclude the possibility of a single tower, the number of different valid tower arrangements is q(n)-1.

This gives this neat O(n^2) time and O(n) space program for counting tower arrangements.

```
def towers(n):
    A = [1] + [0] * n
    for k in xrange(1, n+1):
        for i in xrange(n, k-1, -1):
            A[i] += A[i-k]
    return A[n] - 1

print towers(200)
```

The output is as required:

```
487067745
```

To understand the code, one can observe that `A` stores the first n+1 coefficients of the generating function product(1+x^k) for k=1...infinity. Each time through the `k` loop we add one more term to the product. We can stop at `n` rather than infinity, because subsequent terms of the product do not affect the first n+1 coefficients.

Another, more direct, way to think about the code is to define `T(i, k)` to be the number of tower combinations (including the single tower) with `i` blocks, and where the maximum height of any tower is `k`. Then:

```
T(0, 0) = 1
T(i, 0) = 0 if i > 0

T(i, k) = T(i, k-1)               if i < k
        = T(i, k-1) + T(i-k, k-1) if i >= k
```

Then one can observe that after `j` iterations of the `for k` loop, `A` contains the values of `T(j, i)` for `i` from `0` to `n`. The update is done somewhat carefully, updating the array from the end backwards so that results are changed only after they are used.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give a little more insight into what the code is doing. Just so I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine calling the function answer(6). Your code returns 2, the correct answer however is 3 (5, 1; 4, 2; 3, 2, 1). Why is this? your code stops when the amount of blocks above the bottom tower is greater than the length of the bottom tower, so it sees 3, 3 and stops, it therefor never considers the combination 3, 2, 1.

My advice would be to rethink the function, try to take into account the idea that you can stack a number of blocks N on top of a tower that is less than N high.

Comment: I improved the function to account for what you said. However it still doesn't work with the example of 200 blocks. I think we're getting closer though. Is there some discrete mathematics that could be applied in this scenario perhaps?

Comment: I would reccomend finding examples where your code fails, then try to find why it is failing. The code you posted failed with 6  blocks, so it was easy to run through until I found a mistake. The answer above should allow you to test your code by running through larger and larger numbers of blocks until your codes answer differs with the posted codes answer. Best of luck.